# mysqldump command works when typed directly into command line - but not in a shell script

Tags: shell, centos, mysql

I am just getting started with shell scripts to save me typing in the same commands over and over.  This command is used to copy a database over to a slave server as part of setting up MySQL database replication.

It works when typed into the command prompt directly:

```
mysqldump --host=192.168.1.1  –uUSER –pPASSWORD --opt database_name | mysql --host=192.168.1.2 –uUSER –pPASSWORD -C database_name
```

USER, PASSWORD and database_name all are replaced with their actual values in the real script.

When I type this command into a scripts.sh file, give it the execute permission, and then run it with ./scripts.sh I get:

```
'RROR1102 (42000): Incorrect database name 'database_name
mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write
```

What could be causing this error?  Do I need to modify the command somehow when it is contained in a shell script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable your database name is in has a [CR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) at the end. You may need to run your script through `dos2unix`, or use one of the solutions on this site for stripping CRs from data if you're getting the database name from an external source.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  I typed the command directly into the file using the VI editor, so there is no external source and no CR after the line though...

Comment: If I create a file with VI and type a single line into it and then save, is it possible for me to have added a CR?

Comment: @Dan: Depends on which line ending vi is set up to use by default.

Comment: Ok cool.  Thank you!  I'll start again with the file and investigate the default line return.

Comment: It's working now - I got a CR in there somehow even though it was not visible.  When I started again with a new file it was fine.  I didn't need to change the default line return or anything.  Thanks!